# R cuts the string result from SQL query

Tags: sql, r, odbc

I have a simple query where [column] has character data type. I get a result where all the values is cut to 16 characters length. The string with more than 16 character length is the row number 500 or so, so I guess the r or sql server cuts the length based on the first 100 or 200 lines. Is there a way how to eliminate this?

```
odbc::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT [column] FROM [database]")
```

expected result:

```
column
String
StringString
...
StringStringString
StringStringStringString
```

received result:

```
column
String
StringString
...
StringStringStri
StringStringStri
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you might want to start by checking your ODBC connection settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Tim, your advice actually helped. After changing the cache settings, the output is as expected. Thanks!

[image]